# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (24:2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

So I'm getting this error message saying that I have a syntax error on line 24. Which is the onSearchChange line.

Please someone help me, I've been stuck on this problem for over a day now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          robots: [],
          searchfield: ''
        }
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response=> {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(users => {
      this.setState({ robots: users})
    }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value })
  }

  render() {
      const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
        return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
      })
      return (
        <div className ='tc'>
          <h1 className='f1'> RoboFriends</h1>
          <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render function is inside componentDiDMount. Check for the opening and closing braces.